# Population of field in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a MDM system and Salesforce system which are in sync.
Custom Object A has a Detail object B. A button on A displays a VF Page which fetches data from the MDM and displays.

```
 <apex:page showHeader="false" id="thePage" controller="EmployeeDetails_Controller" standardStylesheets="true"
       action="{!invokeDataFromMDM}" title="Employee Details" tabStyle="Employee__c">
```

Is there a way to fetch rest of the fields through service from MDM and for two fields[Fields are present in Object B] , we will populate from Salesforce?

Comment: is "invokeDataFromMDM" forwarding you to a new page? It's hard to tell whether this is possible without having the full context..

Comment: using page action methods should generally be limited to doing redirects to other pages;  I'm with Guy here -- you'll need to include the bare bones essence of your controller (no code dumps please)